# Bookmarks not automatically generating

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I have `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble of a very simple document, which has defined sections. However, the output pdf file has no bookmarks.

In 4.1 of [this](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-160004.1.1) manual, it's stated that

> Usually hyperref automatically adds bookmarks for \section and similar macros

What am I missing?

Also, surfing a forum, I found that someone said that all he had to was put `\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}` in his preamble... but this did not work for me either.

(I am using the latest version of TeXworks as my editor and I am a PC user.)

Comment: Please add to your question a simple, complete and minimal document illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: I guess you could try loading `hyperref` last. Surprising how often that works.

Comment: Which `hyperref` driver you are using (see the `.log` file)? How do you generate the PDF file? Have you run `latex` at least twice? If you load package `bookmark` after `hyperref`, the bookmarks are faster updated. Which document class is used?

Comment: This is really strange. Could you please a minimal portion of the offending files?